# 16.04 Update not offered via update manager

Tags: update-manager, 16.04

Good morning,

my update manager is not showing the update to 16.04, but if I use the terminal sudo do-release-upgrade -d I'm asked to upgrade. I'm using 14.04. Is it just a matter of time or do we have to update manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Updates to the newest LTS are usually offered when it hits in this case 16.04.1. This is done because LTS releases often run in production enviroments and they want stable releases.

To have a check you can simply do from terminal

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

or

```
do-release.upgrade -cd
```

this will check if there is an actual release. If yes run the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

or respective if you did `-cd`

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Using `-d` will get you a development version which can be an option to get the upgrade going just make sure youre getting the 16.04 and nothing else from that branch.

Comment: It says something like "No new release found", could it be because my Ubuntu is localized in italian?

Comment: In fact what does it tell when you use the -d option ?

Comment: Basically it updates everything and offers me Xenial, just as usual: obsolete package count, download size and everything...

Comment: Use the command like this `do-release-upgrade -cd` to just check which version is offered there. If its Xenial you can get the upgrade going this way.

Comment: With that command it says 16.04 LTS is available, but will this install a develop version or the regular one? I'm quite confused and I'm running this on my main, working laptop

Comment: The developtment version is aswell the version you would get on an iso image.

Comment: So this command line method is basically the same as the regular GUI one? Sorry, just gotta be safe with this one :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38807/discussion-between-videonauth-and-seb).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_or_15.10):

> 14.04 LTS to LTS upgrades will be enabled with the 16.04.1 LTS point release, in approximately 3 months time.

This is for stability reasons, giving Canonical time to iron out bugs in the new release, and in the upgrade process.

Comment: Point release already happened now, the Wiki shows the 16.04.1 release, still the GUI shows only 15.10 as an available upgrade. `do-release-upgrade -cd` shows 16.04 LTS as the available upgrade.

Comment: @karatedog if it's showing 15.10 then th'art on **15**.04, not **14**.04, and skipping intermediate releases is only possible when *both* starting *from* an LTS release and going *to* **another** LTS release.  To get to 16.04 from 15.04 it will be necessary to go via 15.10.

Comment: @Darael problem solved, I was too impatient. The Xubuntu team asked for a few days to complete work on the 16.04.1 release (after the Ubuntu 16.04.1)and I just happened to install this during those day.

Comment: @karatedog fair enough. I honestly wasn't sure if that 15 was a typo and thought I'd better note what I did in case of future readers.